# Why no compile error when not including initializer_list header file?

Tags: c++11, header-files

I've just see someone's blog wrote this example code, illustrating simple usage of initializer_list, appeared in C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <initializer_list>
using namespace std;

void print(initializer_list<int> list) {
    for(auto it = list.begin(); it!=list.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    print({1,2,3,4,5,6,7});
    return 0;
}
```

However, I've tested under Ubuntu16.04 with g++-5.4 and clang++-8, also tested with Visual Studio 2017, they all compile OK, **without any compile error**. I wander why the commented out `#include <initializer_list>` is not required.

My compile command:

```sh
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall
```

By not including `initializer_list` header file, how C++ compiler found its definition?

And also confusious, when should I enforce including `initializer_list` header file?

Figured out under VS2017. It's a long including.

iostream <- istream <- ostream <- ios <- xcolumn <- streambuf <- xiosbase <- xlocale <- stdexcept <- xstring <- xmemory0 <- xutility <- utility <- xstddef <- initializer_list

Answer (score 0):

There is no compiler error because including `<iostream>` will also include `<initializer_list>`.

Answer (score 0):

Not including `<initializer_list>` is undefined behavior. It works in this case because on this particular implementation `<iostream>` includes it, but it is not required to do so.

Comment: Is there any method/trick to enable compiler checking on this?

Comment: @HaxtraZ not that I know of

Answer (score -2):

It should be either included via `<iostream>` header due to being an often used header OR the compiler may be including by default for the same reason of usefulness.

You may want to add `<initializer_list>` only when compiler is complaining for it.